# Unexplained gaps in my academics due to drop out. Hiring manager couldn't find it and has offered the job already

Tags: hiring-process, new-job, human-resources, careers, employment-gaps

I've got an offer for internship at a very reputed company. But they were unable to find out the gaps I had in my academics as I dropped out from college for 3-4 years in spite of getting good grades. The reason was I was involved in some organisational work which interested me more. But later came back and completed my degree again with good grades. So before joining should I take initiative to explain them about the gaps even though they have not found? (Actually anyone can make out that there's a huge gap but they couldn't find.)

Comment: How did you learn that they had not found the gaps?  Aside from that, you are not making sense. If you listed the gap in your CV, they should have found it. If you didn't list it on your CV, then you did a successful hiding job.

Comment: keep calm and carry on. you are obliged to bring it up when you were asked about it.

Comment: What makes you say "they couldn't find it"? Maybe they saw the gap but were not concerned (e.g. because they felt you were a good fit for the role). After all, they offered it to you.

Comment: They may not care about your educational gaps as long as you have completed the degree. Unless you list the years you attended college on your CV and not just the graduation year, they wouldn't know without digging through your transcripts.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you didn't outright lie on your CV, I don't see any reason why it matters whether you paused college at some point and finished it later.  Assuming your resume reads something like "graduated 2015, worked at organization 2012-2014", they could have asked you what you did before 2012 but decided not to, it isn't your responsibility to guess whether or not it didn't occur to them or if they just didn't care.